# Facebook sdk logout

Tags: javascript, facebook, grails

I am using facebook javascript sdk ko authenticate user in my website that I build using Grails 2.1.2. I used the following code to logout user from my application

```
FB.logout(function(response) {
    jQuery.ajax({
                type:'post',
                url:"${createLink(controller:'facebook',action: 'logout')}",
                success:function(result){
                    ${remoteFunction(controller: 'facebook',action: 'updateHeader',update:'header')}
                }
       });
});
```

Buit the problem is, this codes logs out user from facebook as well, how do I logout the user from my app only? How do I invalidate the user's cookies and session ?

Comment: the user is running fb and ur application in same browser instance then if the user logout of ur application fb then the user obviously logs out of the fb in the browser. because they share the same session.

Comment: can i logout the user just from my app ??

Comment: no u cannot. same browser same session is shared.

Comment: And by Facebook’s Platform Policies you are _required_ to provide your users with a possibility to log out of your page _and_ FB at the same time, btw.